# Unable to send Authorization token in headers

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm trying to send a put request to an API. To make it work, i have to send an Authorization token in the headers.

Here's my code :

```
 updatePlaylist(id, name) {
    axios.put(`${config.baseUrl}/playlists/${id}`, { headers: auth.getAuthHeader(), data: { name } })
      .then(() => {
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.error('unable to update tasks');
      });
  },
```

Here's the getAuthHeader function :

```
getAuthHeader() {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'));
    return {
      Authorization: localStorage.getItem('token')
    };
  }
```

The returned token by the getAuthHeader function is the good one.

Now the problem is i always get a 401 error, with no Authorization in the headers. Instead of that, i see this in the Request Payload section when checking with Google Chrome inspector :

```
{headers: {,…}, data: {name: "test"}}
data
:
{name: "test"}
headers
:
{,…}
```

For some reason, my headers are sent with the data.

Anyone knows how to fix it ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are invoking the `axios.put` is incorrect. You are passing the headers in the `data` of the put method, you need to send it as a `config` argument.

```
axios.put(`${config.baseUrl}/playlists/${id}`, {
  name
}, {
  headers: {...getAuthHeader() //, {...otherHeaders} Incase you have to add other headers as well
  }
})
```

> When using the alias methods(post, put, get) the url, method, and data properties don't need to be specified in config. But information regarding `headers` will still go to the config argument.